# Getting Marker Coordinates passed to variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm building an app that allows a user to set a proximity alarm by selecting a marker and clicking on the info window to confirm. I need to be able to get the latitude and longitude from the marker so I can use the coordinates to set up the radius.

```
 googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
   new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
     public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

         //click function
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
        "Info Window clicked@" + marker.getPosition(), 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     LocationManager lm;
     double lat=0;
     double long1=0;    //Defining Latitude & Longitude
     float radius=3000;

    lm=(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Intent i= new Intent("com.example.sleepertrain5.proximityalert");           //Custom Action
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), -1, i, 0);
    lm.addProximityAlert(lat, long1, radius, -1, pi);
```

So far, I've only been able to find `marker.getLocation()` which doesn't allow direct variable setting. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

// Use default InfoWindow frame
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker args) {
    return null;
}

// Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
@Override 
public View getInfoContents(Marker args) 
{
    LatLng clickedMarkerLatLng = args.getPosition();
    double latitude =  clickedMarkerLatLng.latitude;
    double longitude =  clickedMarkerLatLng.longitude;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you :

> ```
> @Override
> public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
>
> Latitude lat = point.getLatitude(); 
> Longitude lng = point.getLongitude();
>
> }
> ```